# Encrypting and Decrypting Affine coded words using javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to code an Affine Encryption Algorithm in JavaSCript.

To begin with I have inserted the alphabet inside a matrix :

```
alpha =['A','B','C','Ç','D','E','Ë','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N'];
```

The number of characters is 90 , so the length of this matrix is 90 
and the module for the algorithm is mod(90).

Also I used `a = 29` because `(29,90)=1` and a<sup>−1</sup> = 59.

The function of encryption includes 3 parameters on it :

```
 encrypt(a, b,word)
```

and inside it I used a for() loop to cycle each character of the inserted word.

So this for loop searches for the characters in the alphabet matrix, gets the index and than uses the encryption function **E(x)=(a*x+b)mod(c)**.

```
function encrypt(a, b, word) {

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

        var alphaIndex = alpha.indexOf(word[i]);

        var troublesome = (a * alphaIndex + b) % alpha.length;

        word = word.substring(0, i) + alpha[troublesome] + word.substring(i + 1);
    }
    return word;
}
```

However this function returns a coded word but when I apply the decrytpion.

function it doesn't return the deciphered word **D(y) = a<sup>−1</sup>(y − b) mod(c)**.

The function of the decryption is :

```
function decrypt(a, b, word) {

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        a %= alpha.length;

        //Bruteforce the modular invert of the a

        for (var j = 1; j < alpha.length; j++) {
            if ((a * j) % alpha.length == 1)
                var invert = j;
        }

        var alphaIndex = alpha.indexOf(word[i]);

        var troublesome = (invert * (alphaIndex - b)) % alpha.length;
        if (troublesome < 0)
            troublesome += alpha.length;
        word = word.substring(0, i) + alpha[troublesome] + word.substring(i + 1);
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with consistent, readable indentation. *(Edit: I've done it for you on this occasion.)*

Comment: 90 is not a prime, so I see no reason it should work.

Comment: what do you mean by prime ? @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0):

There was just one mistake that i should have known since the beginning.
When i get a , b and the word via `document.getElementbyId()` , the value 
is in a `String` state sot thats why i was not getting the right numbers.

```
a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b);
```

This two lines above are the solution.

```
function encrypt(a, b, word) {

a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b); 

    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

        var alphaIndex = alpha.indexOf(word[i]);

        var troublesome = (a * alphaIndex + b) % alpha.length;

        word = word.substring(0, i) + alpha[troublesome] + word.substring(i + 1);
    }
    return word;
}


    function decrypt(a, b, word) {

    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b); 

        for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            a %= alpha.length;

            //Bruteforce the modular invert of the a

            for (var j = 1; j < alpha.length; j++) {
                if ((a * j) % alpha.length == 1)
                    var invert = j;
            }

            var alphaIndex = alpha.indexOf(word[i]);

            var troublesome = (invert * (alphaIndex - b)) % alpha.length;
            if (troublesome < 0)
                troublesome += alpha.length;
            word = word.substring(0, i) + alpha[troublesome] + word.substring(i + 1);
        }
        return word;
    }
```